# How do navbars have smooth scrolls with vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, web

Say I have a navbar at the top of my webpage, do I just use the scrollTo method?  Is there a better way to do it? Sorry if my question sounds stupid.

Comment: Thank you, and I think my problem is that I didn't know what to search.  I always googled how to make a navbar with javascript.  But it didnt show the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

To scroll using javascript on a webpage, such as on a navbar, you can use the scrollTo() method. To make it smooth, you can use the options object, and assign behavior to "smooth" like this:

```
element.scrollTo({
  top: 500,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```